# Alamofire: Where does AF gets totalBytesRead information from?

Tags: swift, ios9, alamofire

I'm thinking about adding a progress bar to my app.

```
Alamofire.download(.GET, imageURL, destination: destination).progress {
                        bytesRead, totalBytesRead, totalBytesExpectedToRead in
```

1. Does the response JSON has to provide this info?  If so, how should it be sent back? i.e. parameters?
2. If the server does not have to provide this, how does AF know how much total data it'll receive ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain [countOfBytesRecived](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionTask_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSURLSessionTask/countOfBytesReceived) from `NSURLSessionTask`.

And with `NSURLSessionDataDelegate` you can use the method 
[URLSession(_:dataTask:didReceiveData:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionDataDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSURLSessionDataDelegate/URLSession:dataTask:didReceiveData:)
 to be notified when `countOfBytesRecieved` changes value

Answer (score 1):

The iOS APIs for these values are exposed by NSURLRequest; the actually total bytes value comes from the server response `Content-Length` HTTP header.